# Apache Lucene returns NaN as score when sorting by relevance

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I want to order the results of my Apache Lucene search by relevance. But when I use `SortField.FIELD_SCORE` for sorting, the score of the resulting documents is always `NaN`.
When I omit the sort parameter, the search works perfectly fine, and the result documents contain a valid score.

I use `lucene-core 9.6.0` and `lucene-analyzers-common 8.11.2` which are the most up to date versions in the Maven repository right now.

At first I thought, I messed up my index or query. But I'm able to reproduce the issue with the most simple implementation I can imagine:

```java
public class LuceneSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Directory directory = new ByteBuffersDirectory();
            
            try (IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer()))) {
                indexWriter.addDocument(createDocument("a very simple example"));
                indexWriter.addDocument(createDocument("another example"));
                indexWriter.addDocument(createDocument("hello world"));
            }

            IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
            IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

            Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("value", "hello"));
            Sort sort = new Sort(SortField.FIELD_SCORE); // <<<< this causes the problem
            TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 10, sort);
            for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
                System.out.println(scoreDoc.doc + " : " + scoreDoc.score);
            }

            indexReader.close();
            directory.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Document createDocument(String value) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new TextField("value", value, Field.Store.NO));
        return document;
    }
}
```

When I run this simple code, I get `2 : NaN`. Without the `sort` parameter, I get `2 : 0.49662238`. I have no idea what I'm missing here. Or could it be a bug in the library?
Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
As @andrewJames stated in the comments, the ScoreDoc (actually `FieldDoc`) object contains a property `fields` which contains the score when using the sort parameter.
After some testing, I found out that the actual score is identical in both cases (with/without sort parameter). So the sorting works correctly.

Comment: Not an answer,just a couple of observations: (1) For Lucene 9.6.0, you need to use [`lucene-analysis-common`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analysis-common). The package was renamed from `analyzers` to `analysis`. Don't mix different JAR versions. (2) The sort you are trying to implement is the default sort order (by score, highest to lowest) - so you can remove it and get the required result (as you mention in the question).

Comment: Some more notes: When you do not try to use an explicit sort, you can retrieve the score from your `ScoreDoc`, which is: `doc=2 score=0.49662238 shardIndex=-1` (as you note). But when you get `NaN` the `ScoreDoc` is this:  `doc=2 score=NaN shardIndex=-1 fields=[0.49662238]`. You can see the `NaN` - but you can also see the score in the `fields` array - which looks very odd to me (but there may be an explanation). I would ask on the Lucene `java-user` mailing list - see [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/discussion.html) for how to subscribe.

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames for the hints! The `fields` property is part of the `FieldDoc` class (a subclass of `ScoreDoc`). The JavaDoc says, that it contains information about how to sort the documents. The `fields` array contains the score in THIS case, because I order by score. But it can also contain other types, depending on the type of the field-type that should be used for sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Sorting will work the way you expect, using your provided `Sort` criterion. It is equivalent to the default "relevance" sort order used by Lucene.

You can still access the relevance score, if you want to, by casting `ScoreDoc` to `FieldDoc`.

---

**Longer Answer**

The sort order defined by:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(SortField.FIELD_SCORE);
```

is the same as the default sort order - which sorts by score (relevance) from highest to lowest. So, documents will be ordered in the same way in both cases.

But when you use an explicit sort, you can no longer access the score using `scoreDoc.score`, as noted in the question. Instead you only get `NaN` (not a number).

```
2 : NaN
```

---

However, you can still access the score (if you want to) by casting each `ScoreDoc` instance to a [`FieldDoc`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldDoc.html). We get `FieldDocs` because we have added a sort field to our search.

`FieldDoc` extends `ScoreDoc`. It contains "information about how to sort the referenced document".

In our case, there is only one sort field and it is the `FIELD_SCORE` value.

So, to print the score, we can change this code:

```java
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
    System.out.println(scoreDoc.doc + " : " + scoreDoc.score);
}
```

to this:

```java
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topFieldDocs.scoreDocs) {
    FieldDoc fieldDoc = (FieldDoc) scoreDoc;
    System.out.println(scoreDoc.doc + " : " + fieldDoc.fields[0]);
}
```

Now we will get the score printed, instead of `NaN`:

```
2 : 0.49662238
```

**Speculation:** I may be wrong, but I assume the original `scoreDoc.score` field is `NaN` because it doesn't make sense to calculate it and store it here, given there is no guarantee that the applied search will use `SortField.FIELD_SCORE`.

I expect users will mostly want to sort by something other than score - and maybe optionally use score as a tie-breaker.

But if `FIELD_SCORE` *is* used, then the score will be available in that field, instead.

---

As an aside, instead of this:

```
TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 10, sort);
```

You can use this:

```
TopFieldDocs topFieldDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 10, sort);
```

This allows us to access `SortField[]` - the fields which were used for sorting results. This includes information about field types.